# I can't see my html when I built container with docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

I have my container running like this
[image]

in the file directory C:\Users\hailey\Desktop\GitTest Where my project file are.

```
# getting bse image nginx
FROM nginx 

MAINTAINER hailey

COPY . /usr/share/nginx/html
```

This is my docker file and I want to run my html file, which located in C:\Users\hailey\Desktop\GitTest
[image]

When I accessed to http://127.0.0.1:8080/
I see only this page, which is not helloWorld.html
[image]

Comment: you need to replace it with index.html or to set nginx to redirect to your html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can copy and replace testhelloWorld.html with index.html

```
COPY testhelloWorld.html /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
```

Comment: I just did and still I see that web page above when I access to  http://127.0.0.1:8080/

Comment: sorry. it works perfectly!!! I didn't refresh the image and that's why it was showing the same default page but after I refresh the image, it works fine! Thanks